# How to grouping facet_counts results into separate categories using multiple Solrnet facet.query parameters?

Tags: solrnet, faceted-search

I have implemented CreateDate Field Search as well Spatial Search, both using facet.query to generate a link like this.
        q=*:*&sfield=latlng&pt=41.3,-73.8&facet.field=AllergenicIngredients&facet.field=FoodType&facet.query=CreateDate:[2013-08-27T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-10T23:00:23Z]&facet.query=CreateDate:[2013-08-28T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-11T23:00:23Z]&facet.query={!frange l=0 u=100}geodist()">&facet.query={!frange l=100.00=3000}geodist()&wt=xml&facet=true&fl=*,*dist*:geodist().

```
The facet_counts element of the response XML looks like this.

<lst name="facet_counts">
    *<lst name="facet_queries">
        <int name="CreateDate:[2013-08-27T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-10T23:00:23Z]">7</int>
        <int name="CreateDate:[2013-08-28T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-11T23:00:23Z]">4</int>
        <int name="{!frange l=0 u=100}geodist()">2</int>
        <int name="{!frange l=100.001 u=3000}geodist()">6</int>
    </lst>*
    <lst name="facet_fields">
      <lst name="AllergenicIngredients">
        <int name="Not Allergenic">6</int>
        <int name="Nuts">2</int>
      </lst>
      <lst name="FoodType">
        <int name="Non-Vegetarian">6</int>
        <int name="Vegetarian">2</int>
      </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="facet_dates"/>
    <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>


I am able to group the facet_fields count results by their names(AllergenicIngredients,FoodType) but how do I group the facet_queries (*italicized*) count by CreatDate and Distance. My website is .Net based and is using Solrnet.
```

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#key_:_Changing_the_output_key

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: Thanks for the quick response, Maurico! facet.field={!ex=dt key=mylabel}doctype but I am concerned about this output. <lst name="facet_counts">
    *<lst name="facet_queries">
        <int name="CreateDate:[2013-08-27T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-10T23:00:23Z]">7</int>
        <int name="CreateDate:[2013-08-28T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-11T23:00:23Z]">4</int>
        <int name="{!frange l=0 u=100}geodist()">2</int>
        <int name="{!frange l=100.001 u=3000}geodist()">6</int>
    </lst>*

Comment: Apply the `key` to the facet *query*, which is your problem, not the facet *field*.

Comment: Thanks again. I am not able to explain what I need. Can I not get an output like this?<lst name="facet_counts">
 <lst name="facet_queries">
   <lst name="CreateDate">
  <int name="CreateDate:[2013-08-27T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-10T23:00:23Z]">7</int>
  <int name="CreateDate:[2013-08-28T23:00:23Z TO 2013-09-11T23:00:23Z]">4</int>
          </lst>
          <lst name="Distance">
  <int name="{!frange l=0 u=100}geodist()">2</int>
  <int name="{!frange l=100.001 u=3000}geodist()">6</int>
   </lst>
 </lst>

Comment: As far as I know you can't, but you don't really need to.

Comment: ok. thanks. I will try to work with whatever I have.